# Julia: How to obtain all but one point from an array?

Tags: julia

Say `x = [1:5..]` and I wish to return an array with the element `1:2` and `4:5` i.e. all but one element namely `3`. How do I do that?

I tried `x[1:2; 4:end]` and `x[1:2 4:end]`. Neither worked.

I would really like to use the `end` keyword if possible.

Comment: Try `x[[1:2; 4:5]]`.

Answer (score 3):

[InvertedIndices.jl](https://github.com/mbauman/InvertedIndices.jl) has a nice interface for this:

```
julia> using InvertedIndices

julia> v = map(i -> i => rand(), 1:5)
5-element Array{Pair{Int64,Float64},1}:
 1 => 0.8165266824627073
 2 => 0.38840874144349025
 3 => 0.061178225310028145
 4 => 0.6615139442678073
 5 => 0.10733363621427094

julia> v[Not(3)]
4-element Array{Pair{Int64,Float64},1}:
 1 => 0.8165266824627073
 2 => 0.38840874144349025
 4 => 0.6615139442678073
 5 => 0.10733363621427094
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a union of the indices:

```
julia> x = [1:5..]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
julia> x[(1:2) ∪ (4:end) ]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
 5
```

I typed the "union" symbol by writing `\cup` and hitting TAB